# Creating a simple windows instance capable of rendering Direct3D graphics

Tags: c++, beginner, windows

I've just started to learn recently about Direct3D, when I've learned to create a simple window I started wondering if I could automate this process, so whenever I would need to create a window I would just need to call for a function with my configs already setup. This is the essential part of the code I've come out:

```
void CreateWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
//Inside this function is the code used to create a simple window.
{
HWND hWnd;
WNDCLASSEX(wc);
ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.lpszClassName = L"D3D11Class";
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;

RegisterClassEx(&wc);

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"D3D11Class", L"WINDOW", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 50, 50, 1080, 720, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
Init3D(hWnd);
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
//The main function where the CreateWindow function was called, also used a loop to keep it running.
{
std::atexit(CleanD3D);
CreateWindow(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);
MSG msg;
while (true)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    RenderFrame();
}
return msg.wParam;
}
```

Some of the functions I've used wasn't pasted here because I think they were irrelevant to what I want to be reviewed. Everything seems to be running fine when I execute the application, but I don't have sure this is the right way of doing things as I'm just a beginner, so if anyone which is more experienced on DirectX coding could advise me I would be thankfull.